# Magento: how to transfer shop settings to the default scope?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

One of my shops was set up improperly, and many setting were made in scope_id 1, instead of 0.

I need to find all the settings made in scope_id 1 and transfer (copy them) into scope id 0. Then, maybe, I can delete these from scope_id 1.

Using which SQL query this can be done?

Thanks in advance for all the answers.

[image: core_config_data table view]

Comment: In your image the records are added to `scope_id` 0 so what is the problem? And also is the `scope_id` on;ly difference, or some other values are also different?

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear. The image is just an example of table structure. Of course, other values are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by doing an [update join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/) where you join `core_config_data` to itself and set a condition on each of the joined tables `scope_id`, then you just delete the store 1 values so they do not override the store 0 settings:

```
update core_config_data store0
left join core_config_data store1
on store1.path = store0.path
where store0.scope_id = 0
and store1.scope_id = 1
and store1.value is not null;
```

After the update above, you could check your scope=0 values to be sure before running the delete statement below:

```
delete from core_config_data where scope_id = 1;
```